# installing android sdk in android studio

Tags: software-installation, android-studio

For some reason I couldn't download Android Studio and Android Studio bundle. I download them both separate each other. In install section of Android Studio there is a part to specify Android SDK location. I locate the Android SDK folder and go on but this error message appears for no reason:

[image: android sdk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my way to install Android Studio in Ubuntu.

Open your terminal and input the commands below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android studio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try umake:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
umake android --accept-license
```

better for most development type stuff.

Note:  you must accept the license as above.